# How do I retrieve JavaScriptObject key/value in AbstractPresenterModule in GWTP?

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, gwtp, gwt-platform

I use GWTP and want to use a [Dictionary](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/Dictionary.html) in my AbstractPresenterModule. My static host page has the following JavaScriptObject:

```
var CurrentTheme = {
  highlightColor: "#FFFFFF",
  shadowColor: "#808080",
  errorColor: "#FF0000",
  errorIconSrc: "stopsign.gif"
};
```

and in my AbstractPresenterModule:

```
public class AppModule extends AbstractPresenterModule {

@Override
protected void configure() {

         Dictionary xx = Dictionary.getDictionary("Properties");



 }
}
```

This raises the following error:

```
15:49:15.657 [ERROR] [mobile] (Dictionary.java:-2) 2014-04-01 15:49:15,635 [FATAL] Uncaught Exception:
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.ApplicationControllerImpl.init(ApplicationControllerImpl.java:9)
    at test.mobile.client.Mobile.startApplication(Mobile.java:67)
    at test.mobile.client.Mobile$1.execute(Mobile.java:32)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.SchedulerImpl$Task$.executeScheduled$(SchedulerImpl.java:50)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.SchedulerImpl.runScheduledTasks(SchedulerImpl.java:180)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.SchedulerImpl.flushPostEventPumpCommands(SchedulerImpl.java:345)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.SchedulerImpl$Flusher.execute(SchedulerImpl.java:78)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.SchedulerImpl.execute(SchedulerImpl.java:138)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:338)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:219)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:576)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:284)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:347)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:293)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:547)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Deferred binding failed for 'com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.DesktopGinjector' (did you forget to inherit a required module?)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.GWTBridgeImpl.create(GWTBridgeImpl.java:53)
    at com.google.gwt.core.shared.GWT.create(GWT.java:72)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.create(GWT.java:86)
    at com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.DesktopGinjectorProvider.get(DesktopGinjectorProvider.java:8)
    at com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.ClientGinjector.<clinit>(ClientGinjector.java:11)
    at com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.ApplicationControllerImpl.init(ApplicationControllerImpl.java:9)
    at test.mobile.client.Mobile.startApplication(Mobile.java:67)
    at test.mobile.client.Mobile$1.execute(Mobile.java:32)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.SchedulerImpl$Task$.executeScheduled$(SchedulerImpl.java:50)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.SchedulerImpl.runScheduledTasks(SchedulerImpl.java:180)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.SchedulerImpl.flushPostEventPumpCommands(SchedulerImpl.java:345)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.SchedulerImpl$Flusher.execute(SchedulerImpl.java:78)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.SchedulerImpl.execute(SchedulerImpl.java:138)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:338)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:219)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:576)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:284)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:347)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:293)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:547)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.google.gwt.i18n.client.Dictionary.attach(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at com.google.gwt.i18n.client.Dictionary.attach(Native Method)
    at com.google.gwt.i18n.client.Dictionary.<init>(Dictionary.java:120)
    at com.google.gwt.i18n.client.Dictionary.getDictionary(Dictionary.java:93)
    at test.mobile.client.gin.WebAppModule.configure(WebAppModule.java:25)
    at com.google.gwt.inject.client.AbstractGinModule.configure(AbstractGinModule.java:46)
    at com.google.gwt.inject.rebind.adapter.GinModuleAdapter.configure(GinModuleAdapter.java:57)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:223)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:101)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:92)
    at com.google.gwt.inject.rebind.BindingsProcessor.createBindingsForModules(BindingsProcessor.java:201)
    at com.google.gwt.inject.rebind.BindingsProcessor.process(BindingsProcessor.java:102)
    at com.google.gwt.inject.rebind.GinjectorGeneratorImpl.generate(GinjectorGeneratorImpl.java:79)
    at com.google.gwt.inject.rebind.GinjectorGenerator.generate(GinjectorGenerator.java:74)
    at com.google.gwt.core.ext.IncrementalGenerator.generateNonIncrementally(IncrementalGenerator.java:40)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.StandardGeneratorContext.runGeneratorIncrementally(StandardGeneratorContext.java:676)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.RuleGenerateWith.realize(RuleGenerateWith.java:41)
```

**How can I access the JavaScriptObject from my Module class?**

Comment: Is your JS object properly named "Properties" ?

Comment: @Simon-Pierre Yes! The same code works perfect in my entry point.

Comment: Ah I see, that's because you're using Dictionary in a Gin module. This won't work, as Gin executes at compile-time (before your app runs). Dictionary uses JSNI (which uses the browser's APIs), and won't work during compilation.

You should retrieve your Dictionary in your EntryPoint then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Gin's docs https://code.google.com/p/google-gin/wiki/GinFaq:

> Because your Module class is actually executed at compile time, you have to make sure its configure(...) method does not execute any GWT client-side code directly.

Therefore, you cannot use `Dictionary` inside the `configure` method of your `AbstractPresenterModule`.